# Why does member function of class template get constructed in this case?

Tags: c++

```
struct ABC {};

template<typename T>
class DEF
{
   void f0(typename T::ab) {} //ERROR
   void f1() {typename T::ab var;} //Fine
};

DEF<ABC> obj;
```

I thought if I don't use a particular member function of a class template it never gets constructed by the compiler. Hence as expected even with `f1()` the code compiles fine because `obj` never uses it. Why does the presence of `f0()` result in compile error? I'm not using that too.

{MinGW g++ 4.7.2, Windows 7}

Comment: what does the compiler error say?

Comment: error: no type named 'ab' in 'struct ABC'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each member function *declaration* is an integral part of the entire *class definition*. Meanwhile, member function *definition* is a completely independent entity, which is not a part of class definition.

When you instantiate an object of some specialized template class, you are instantiating the entire definition of that class, i.e. you are "using" the entire definition of that class, which in turn means that you are "using" all member declarations as well.

Below is the part that turns into the class *definition* in your case, once the template is specialized

```
template<typename T>
class DEF
{
   void f0(typename T::ab);
   void f1();
};
```

All the above has to be valid for the given value of `T` in order for the class definition to be usable, i.e. in order to be able to declare `DEF<ABC> obj;`.

Meanwhile the definition of

```
template<typename T> void DEF<T>::f1() 
{
  typename T::ab var;
}
```

is an independent template. It is only instantiated if you use `f1`.

Comment: ok. I've been quoted this part of the standard which seems to explain what you all say:
 quote 14.7.2

`The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit instantiation of the declarations, but not of the definitions or the class member functions`

Answer (score 2):

The compiler at least needs a valid prototype for the function to then determine if it is used (and then subsequently compile the body or not).

Answer (score 2):

It is because of lazy instantiation. When you do `DEF<ABC> obj`. The compiler will look at the prototype/definition of the class DEF. Thus `void f0(typename T::ab)` fails because ab doesn't exist and you get a compile error.

The reason why you don't get a compiler error for `void f1(){typename T::ab var}` is because it has never been instantiated. If you do `obj.f1()`, you will see that it will error out the same message as the one associated with DEF::f0.